# How did Cell survive and teleport back after blowing himself up?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the episode where Cell (in his 2nd form) was trying to blow himself up along with the others, Goku teleported him to King Kai's planet to prevent him from destroying Earth.

How did Cell get back to Earth after self-destructing, while Goku and King Kai were killed? Not only that, how he was he able to stay alive in his 3rd or perfect form?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Along with Piccolo's regeneration, he has Frieza's ability to survive in space; after Cell achieves his Super Perfect Form due to his brush with death when he self-destructs, he explains in the original English dub of the anime that this is *because each individual cell in his body has a life-force of their own.* When he self-destruct along with Goku in King Kai planet, he stated that there were remaining cells that were not destroyed and had stored the state of his final form. The same cells merged with Goku's cells, thus enabling him to learn the Instant Transmission technique and initiate it.

Comment: Oh I see. But he should only regenerate to his current form before he exploded which is the 2nd form right? How did he got back to Perfect form without consuming Android 18?

Comment: it is called *Super Perfect Cell*. Super Perfect Cell (超完全体セル, Cho Kanzentai Seru) is a version of Cell's perfect form after he receives a Zenkai from his recovery after a botched self-destruction that takes the lives of Goku, King Kai, Bubbles and Gregory. Despite Cell's loss of Android 18 (and after he self-destructs, Android 17), his cells retain the memory of his Perfect Form, which makes it possible for him to regenerate back into that form. He also gained the *zenkai*. An ability of saiyan to become stronger after surviving a near death experience.

Comment: Frieza couldn't survive _any_ injury. He didn't survive his own attack and Trunk's sword and Cell learnt the IT technique when his cells merged with Goku's (who was also blown up).

Comment: *It's called cheating. Deal with it!* Jokes aside though, the other person above explained it pretty well.